# while reading the data of third table t3, check the conditions whether string in table t1 = table t2.

Tags: sql, laravel

I have a table t3 from which i am trying to retrieve data. but before that i want to check for a condition based on table t1 and table t2.

My code so far is:

```
    $department = "billing";
 $durationvsyear = graphdata::select(DB::raw("SUM(amount) as amount"))
                         ->rightjoin('users', 'users.name', '=', 'departments.department')
                         ->groupBy('userid')
                         ->groupBy(DB::raw("year(created_at)"))
                         ->get();
```

Now i am trying to get the total amount from table t3 and i want to check whether the user for which i am trying to get the total amount belong to the department defined.

Relation 
    t3 - only user name is present
    t2 - department manager and his department
    t1 - member in the department.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show us sample data along with the raw MySQL query, if you have already written it.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Raw Mysql query. - Select SUM(amount) from t3 where t1.department = t2.department;